# How to resize NavigationView and SplitView in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation

I want to enable user to resize the NavigationView in my UWP app. Couldn't find any resources how I could do that.

I see some of the apps have "Resizable splitView" but for SplitView also, I cannot see any such resize property exposed to set by default.

Pls help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There are no such property can resize SplitView and NavigationView, you need to custom layout to implement a similar effect. You could use [Slider control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/slider) and bind the `OpenPaneLength` Property of SplitView to `Slider.Value` to do this. Please refer to the following code.

```
     <Grid>

       <SplitView Name="CoreSplitView"          
            DisplayMode="Inline"
            IsPaneOpen="True"
            OpenPaneLength="{Binding Value, ElementName=MasterSlider, Mode=OneWay}">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid Name="PaneGrid" Background="Gray">
                    <Slider Name="MasterSlider"
                        MinWidth="480"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Maximum="480"
                        Minimum="10"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Value="150" 
                           />
                    <StackPanel Name="PaneStackPanel" 
                     Margin="0,0,10,0" Background="LightGray">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Use a slider when you want your users to be able to set defined, contiguous values (such as volume or brightness) or a range of discrete values (such as screen resolution settings).A slider is a good choice when you know that users think of the value as a relative quantity" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid Name="ContentGrid" Background="LightSteelBlue">
            </Grid>
        </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

The StackPanel that is directly under our slider, acts like a cover for our Slider. Notice the StackPanel has Margin="0,0,10,0", this translates to a 10px distance from the right wall, which allows the Slider area to be exposed as a gray strip that is used to drag the Pane, again the 10px is arbitrary but it has to match the Minimum of the Slider.

Comment: Sorry, but is there any workaround using "xaml.primitives.Thumb" ?

Comment: In fact, the [Slider control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider?view=winrt-20348#remarks) has the built-in thumb control, which allows the user to select from a range of values by moving the Thumb control along the track. In a way, the above solution has been implemented with thumb.